# how to prevent re-render when handle onclick

Tags: html, reactjs

```
let inner=useRef();
  let inner_exit=useRef();
  useEffect(()=>{
    inner.current=document.querySelectorAll('.inner');
    inner_exit.current=document.querySelectorAll('.exit');
    
     inner_exit.current?.[0].addEventListener("click",toogleInner);
    inner.current?.[0].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
      if(e.target === e.currentTarget) toogleInner();
    });
    
  },)
  const toogleInner = ()=>{
    inner.current?.[0].classList.toggle('hide');
  };
 
    return (
    <div className='inner'>
      <div className='contentSign'>
        <div className='form'>
        <h2>Đăng nhập</h2>
        <span className='exit'>X</span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  )    
};
```

I want when i click on space or tag span "X"  tag div class "inner" to be hide, but when I click it, it re-renders twice. I find many ways, like: `useCallBack`, use Memo, but I don't know how to use them for my code.Can you fix it for me, please?

I don't know how to fix this bug

Comment: you are using the `React.StrictMode` remote from the `main.jsx` or `main.tsx` file because in the development it loads two times

Answer (score 0):

This is poor react. It is not common to use direct DOM APIs to add event listeners in react (it's not forbidden, just not the norm).

Also, the "number of renders" is almost never something you should ever be concerned about. You should also never try to optimize performance if you don't have a performance problem (or imminently foresee one)

Trying to avoid the render defeats the entire purpose of using react for it's ability to provide simplicity and rapid development.

Writing code like you have above will not improve your React skills.

```
    const [isVisible,setIsVisible] = useState(true)
 
    return (
      <div className={`inner ${isVisible ? '' : 'hide'}`}>
        <div className='contentSign'>
          <div className='form'>
          <h2>Đăng nhập</h2>
          <span className='exit' onClick={() => setIsVisible(false)}>X</span>
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
```